# Short record of if / null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code:

```
decimal? sumFreightAmount = (db.Trips
          .Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
          .Sum(p => p.FreightAmount));

if (sumFreightAmount.HasValue)
{
     // my actions
}
else
{
    sumFreightAmount = 0;
}
```

I can write it the following way:

```
decimal sumFreightAmount = (
         db.Trips
           .Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
           .Sum(p => p.FreightAmount) != null)
         ?
         (db.Trips
            .Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .Sum(p => p.FreightAmount)) : 0;
```

but in this place I call linq extension twice (and have a long record). I have read, that I can write more shorter it in the latest version of C#, like

```
decimal sumFreightAmount = (db.Trips.Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(p => p.FreightAmount)?.0;
```

but can't find it. What is the shortest record?

Comment: I think you want to do so `(db.Trips.Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(p => p.FreightAmount)??0M;`

Comment: `Sum` returns decimal, so no need to check for `null` here.

Comment: it says, that returns <code>decimal?</code>. Null can be returned when no records found at all

Comment: @OlegSh Repeating that whole subexpression is a bad idea; it takes far too much effort to figure out what the whole thing is doing, even if Linq to SQL will optimize out the redundancy (will it?)

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I agree with you, I just answered, that Sum can returns null (when no records found)

Comment: @OlegSh Yes, I understand. But that's not a good reason to sacrifice readability. If `GetValueOrDefault()` and `??` didn't exist, the answer would be to assign the nullable result of the LINQ to a local, and then something like this: `decimal sumFreightAmount = maybeNullDecimalResult ?? 0m;` (or the conditional operator equivalent). Don't go to extremes just to make something a one-liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is using `GetValueOrDefault`

```
decimal sumFreightAmount = db.Trips
    .Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
    .Sum(p => p.FreightAmount)
    .GetValueOrDefault();
```

EDIT: As @IvanStoev pointed out, you can also use the null coalescing operator in this case, which is a tad bit shorter:

```
decimal sumFreightAmount = db.Trips
    .Where(p => p.DateTime.Month == i && p.DateTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
    .Sum(p => p.FreightAmount) ?? 0;
```

Comment: Can you indent that a bit?

Comment: @EdPlunkett yeah I thought the same thing, edited haha

Comment: @RobertPetz you want to say that doing some operation(checking) for all the values in the `db.Trips` which passed `Where` is better than cheking only the result?

Comment: @S.Petrosov no, I did not catch that this was Linq to SQL - I was answering the issue of the cleanest way to nullable check.  The answer is still the same regardless though and I'll update it to reflect the more efficient way of doing that.

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault` or `?? 0` doesn't really matter (I prefer the second). The important thing though is that they have to be applied *after* the `Sum`, not inside. Otherwise, if the `Where` does not match any record - boom, exception :)

Comment: @IvanStoev yup, didn't catch that this was a SQL query - fixed the answer

Comment: @IvanStoev updated with the null coalescing operator as well since it's definitely shorter - forgot you could use that against `Nullable<T>`, I need coffee still lol

Comment: @IvanStoev, not exception, it's just not compiled at all.

Comment: @OlegSh Lol, that was unclear from your post - I was thinking `FreightAmount` property type is nullable. If it's not, then you should promote it inside the `Sum`, e.g. `Sum(p => (double?)p.FreightAmount)` (to avoid the exception) and then convert the result to non nullable by applying `?? 0`

Comment: `FreightAmount` absolutely is nullable in this case - otherwise the return type of the `Sum` would not be nullable.  promoting the cast or null check of any kind into the `Sum` operation was my original answer, but it is inefficient to repeat that check for each record instead of once at the end.